# Extract page from start_urls and find pdf link from every extracted page using Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to extract some fields from start_url, and want to add the PDF link fields that are obtained from each URL that has been obtained. I tried Scrapy but no lucky to add PDF fields. Here is my code,

```py
import scrapy


class MybookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mybooks'
    allowed_domains = ['gln.kemdikbud.go.id']
    start_urls = ['https://gln.kemdikbud.go.id/glnsite/category/modul-gls/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        #pass
        # gathering all links
        book_urls = response.xpath("//div[@class='td-module-thumb']//a/@href").getall()
        total_url = len(book_urls)
        i = 0
        for a in range(total_url):
            title = response.xpath("//h3[@class='entry-title td-module-title']//a/text()")[i].extract()
            url_source = response.xpath("//div[@class='td-module-thumb']//a/@href")[i].get()
            thumbnail = response.xpath('//*[@class="td-block-span4"]//*[has-class("entry-thumb")]//@src')[i].extract()
            pdf = scrapy.Request(book_urls[i], self.find_details)
            yield {
                'Book Title': title,
                'URL': url_source,
                'Mini IMG': thumbnail,
                'PDF Link': pdf
            }
            
            i+=1 
        

    def find_details(self, response):
        # find PDF link
        pdf = response.xpath("//div[@class='td-post-content']//a/@href").get()
        return pdf
```

How do I add a PDF link field correctly when I export it as CSV? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pdf = scrapy.Request(book_urls[i], self.find_details)

It means `pdf` variable is a request.

Scrapy is asynchronous so you'll have trouble to get a return value from a function. Just make a request and pass the details to the callback with [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs).

```py
import scrapy


class MybookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mybooks'
    allowed_domains = ['gln.kemdikbud.go.id']
    start_urls = ['https://gln.kemdikbud.go.id/glnsite/category/modul-gls/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # gathering all links
        book_urls = response.xpath("//div[@class='td-module-thumb']//a/@href").getall()
        total_url = len(book_urls)

        for i in range(total_url):
            item = dict()
            item['title'] = response.xpath("//h3[@class='entry-title td-module-title']//a/text()")[i].extract()
            item['url_source'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='td-module-thumb']//a/@href")[i].get()
            item['thumbnail'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="td-block-span4"]//*[has-class("entry-thumb")]//@src')[i].extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=book_urls[i], callback=self.find_details, cb_kwargs={'item': item})

    def find_details(self, response, item):
        # find PDF link
        item['pdf'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='td-post-content']//a/@href").get()
        yield item
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you so much, I learned a lesson here